# Is there an option to fit image size within a button?

Tags: red

If %heads.jpg is big, in the case of button it won't resize:

```
    view [
        image 140x140 %heads.jpg
        button 140x140 %heads.jpg
    ]
```

Is there an option to fit image size within a button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one, though currently only supported on Windows:

```
view [button 140x140 %head.png with [image: reduce [image size]]
```

So this changes the `/image` facet of the button face, to refer to a block containing the image value and a new target size for the image.